# How do you apply regex in pandas dataframe to extract all values after the first colon (not the second colon)?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a table where column A has values in '12:30:45' format. I want to create a column B where I only get the digits after the first colon of column A.

How do you use regex on python to extract only the digits after the first colon so that in the end, we get ':30:45'?

I've seen regex for extracting numbers, strings, split values between spaces, but couldn't find the one for extracting after colon.

I'm new to regex and any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you use `^([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)` then you can extract all the fields from the returned match object.

Or just use string.split(':') to split on colons and then use the second field from the array returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with `regex` to get the `:` including:

```
# Print reproducable example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['12:30:45', '10:44:09', '8888']})
print(df)

          A
0  12:30:45
1  10:44:09
2      8888
```

---

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str.extract('^[^:]*(:.*)$')

print(df)
        A
0  :30:45
1  :44:09
2     NaN
```

If you want to **keep** the numbers which don't have a `:`, so you don't get a `NaN`, use the regex fallback `|.*` which you can read as: `or all`:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str.extract('(^[^:]*(:.*)$|.*)')
print(df)
          A
0  12:30:45
1  10:44:09
2      8888
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.str.split` limiting the number of splits to `n=1`.

```
print(df)
                  time
0             12:30:45
1                12:30
2                12312
3  1:123:123123:123123

df.time.str.split(':', n=1).str[1]
#0                30:45
#1                   30
#2                  NaN
#3    123:123123:123123
#Name: time, dtype: object
```

---

If you really need the leading semi-colon `':'+df.time.str.split(':', n=1).str[1]'`.